# Filter a view based on an array of values

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a view to temporarily expose the various documents that are missing a specific column value.
I thought I could create a calculated column with a simple clause that states **=IF([DOCREF] IN ("AB001","AB002","AB003","XY110","XY111") THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y'** kinda thing.

It doesn't work like that, obviously so is there a way to pass an array to a simple IF formula?

Answer (score 0):

In your calculated column replace **IN** with **OR** as shown in the formula below.

```
=IF(OR(DOCREF="AB001",DOCREF="AB002",DOCREF="XY003",DOCREF="XY110",DOCREF="XY111"),"X","Y")
```

Works for SP2013

[image]